# Who has been calling you?

Tags: meaning-in-context

If my friend keeps getting phone calls and I ask "who has been calling you?" does it necessarily mean one person keeps calling or could it be different people calling throughout the day?

Comment: It could mean either. More idiomatic for the first meaning might be "who keeps calling you?"; for the second "who's been calling you today?"